# cpp: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c++

I have a weird issue I have just got with C++.

While I am compiling my program, I am getting this:

> cpp: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable

It is in SCO, but I am not sure if it is only a SCO thing or maybe it is to do with all Linux Systems.

I have had a look on several sites, and they say it could be that *"basically g++ is trying to create (fork) a new process, and the kernel is saying No"* - [Touchtecservers answer](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/145610-terminal-giving-error.html)

I asked this question in [U&L chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux), and they said to ask it here.

**Edit**

I have tried adding:

```
#define vfork fork
```

To the source file, and that didn't work.

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: @Claudio Normally good advice but it hardly seems relevant for this question. Presumably any code has this problem.

Comment: @Claudio It is private code, sorry.

Comment: Just to be sure he calls vfork() in the right way (even if I don't see how it could be possibly wrong).

Comment: Have you reached the maximum amount of threads/processes in the system ?

Comment: @Claudio any way I could check that? The memory is 2GB (which is more than enough for this machine)

Comment: Looks like the C preprocessor has a problem allocating a new subprocess. Maybe it tries to process an include tree that is to big to fit in memory?

Comment: @Claudio It's not about the OPs executable, but the compilation process itself that fails on `vfork()`, the preprocessor in particular.

Comment: That is what I thought too @g-makulik, surely there is a way around it though? Like maybe increasing the size of the kernel - that is where I am clueless

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message is from the compiler itself, not directly anything to do with the source code in the program you are compiling.  Indeed, because the compiler has been unable to launch the `cpp` process, your source code has (probably) not been looked at yet.  It's slightly unusual that it is `cpp` that is reported as the process name; I'd expect it to be the `cc` compiler driver that launched `cpp` (so it would normally report `cc: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable`).

Basically, the machine is trying to do too much and doesn't have the resources left over to fork a new process.  If you're running a `make -j8` to do parallel compilations, maybe you should reduce the `8` to `4`.  Otherwise, look at what else is going on the machine that you can stop.

Comment: Yeah I have just looked at all the processors running, and can't see any process I can just kill off (looks like they are all needed).

Comment: In that case, you have a problem.  Time to upgrade the memory available on the machine? Time to get a new machine? Time to configure more swap space? Time to compile on a different machine that isn't as heavily loaded? It isn't entirely clear which resource you're running out of.  It might be that you've got too many processes running.  Anyway, the diagnosis "machine is too busy" holds — it's just the details.  (In passing, I note that SCO Unix is not Linux at all. They provide much the same functionality, but they are completely separate code bases.)

Comment: I upgraded the memory from 1GB to 2GB, but still had this issue - seems like I'm stuck :/ I will try killing off a process (PID), and if it causes issues, I will just restart the machine - it is a Virtual Machine

Comment: Have you ever been able to compile C++ on the VM? Is there something new or unusual about the code you are compiling (trying to compile) compared with code that has compiled before? Is there massive template metaprogramming, for example, requiring the compiler to do computations at compile time?  It's almost criminal to suggest it (I still remember the performance boost I got when my machine was upgraded from 1 MiB to 2 MiB — yes, megabytes! — 30-odd years ago), but can you go larger still with the VM memory? Is there anything else running in the VM? Is it just one file that causes problems?

Comment: So far it is only the one file, but if I fix that issue, then there may be another file that causes an issue. I can up the memory to a lot more, about 8GB, but it doesn't need that much. I am trying to re-install gcc, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you compiled that code successfully on any machine? Did you use a comparable version of GCC (`g++`) when you did? It sounds as if there's something odd about that one file. Have you tried compiling it without optimization? Have you tried to split the file up so you can find what is causing the trouble? Have you run `make -k` to ignore the failure from this one file. The compilation will continue, and if none of the other files have a problem, you know you only need to concentrate on this one. If many have problems… I don't have any simple solutions left; I'm not sure that there are any.

Comment: Thanks for your help though, greatly appreciated. I have compiled my code successfully on other machines (Solaris on SPARC and Intel, Ubuntu, and FreeBSD). I used to use this SCO machine fine, with this compiler on it, but the machine expired, so had to start from scratch again, hence the issues now. I documented everything too, but maybe I am missing out something, that missed the documentation.